# Effect of engine oil on piston rings

Tags: oil, piston-ring

I reassembled my pistons and put new rings in. After some trouble with leaky valves, I re-ground them, sealed them tight, and put the head back on. I was getting pretty good leakdown results (using an air compressor), somewhere between 86-92% retention (14-8% leak), which is below the 20% threshold. But then I remembered reading somewhere that lubing the cylinder sleeves provides a better simulation of the engine runtime and would also improve compression so I poured 3-4 drops of oil in each cylinder through the spark plug hole. I went to re-rest leakdown and this time it was leaking 30-40%. The only thing that changed, literally in a matter of 5 min, was that I added some oil.

Was this a wrong thing to do? Are the compression rings (the upper two) supposed to be dry of oil and now I lubed them and thereby compromised their seal? Does oil compromise the expansion of the compression rings, seizing them shut? I know the bottom 3 are supposed to be scraping the oil but they never reach the very top of the cylinder even in TDC, leaving the compression rings lubed. Does that explain why the leak suddenly increased.

Comment: Has the engine been run since re-assembly? If it has not and the engine is not broken in, it's a guessing game. The rings need to seat first. If they haven't, your readings will vary, with or without oil. If you put it together right, you put oil on the pistons/rings to get them back in the bores. Putting oil in the cylinders isn't going to do much for you because it's already there. 3-4 drops of oil isn't going to make a difference anyways. When the suggestion is to do a compression test, they are talking about a couple squirts of oil from an oil can, not drops.

Comment: not run yet. I am testing the seat with an air compressor and leakdown tool. I am reluctant to proceed with reassembly before I get readings like <=10% leak.

Comment: are you saying it's not realistic to expect good seal before the engine has been run?

Comment: Correct. Until the rings are seated, you cannot expect to get good or even consistent readings.

Comment: So do you think it's safe to proceed with some cylinders leaking 40% as is ?

Comment: At some point you have to be secure in your work. If you've done everything right to the best of your ability, then go forward with it. If you doubt your work, then all bets are off. It is my "opinion" you should put everything together and send it. Get the rings seated, then try your test again.

Comment: I get that but I like thorough testing every step of the way.

Comment: Testing is not a bad thing, but if you are testing out of order, it doesn't make any sense. Test for the right things at the right time.

Comment: the reason i am not sold i shouldn't expect all the cylinders to be fully sealed at this stage is that some of them seem to be